# Is this proof that group elements in the same conjugacy class have the same order incomplete?

Tags: group-theory

My question is similar to the question asked here: [If two elements belong to the same conjugacy class then they have the same order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121347/if-two-elements-belong-to-the-same-conjugacy-class-then-they-have-the-same-order), but none of the answers there seem to answer what is confusing me.

My lecture notes give the following proof:

Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements in group $G$ that are in the same conjugacy class. We also let $n$ be the smallest possible integer s.t. $a^n=e$, where $e$ is the identity element in $G$. An arbitrary conjugate $b$ of $a$ is $b=gag^{-1}$, for some element $g$ in $G$. Then,

$$b^n=(gag^{-1})(gag^{-1})(gag^{-1})...(gag^{-1})=ga^ng^{-1}=geg^{-1}=e$$

The proof then concludes that this is sufficient to show that $b$ is also of the order $n$. But wouldn't it also be necessary to prove that there is no $k<n$ s.t. $b^k=e$, i.e. to me this proof only shows that there $b$ is at most the same order as $a$, but it does not prove that it can't be of a smaller order. Why is this not an issue then?

Comment: The proof is 'if $a$ is conjugate to $b$ then $a^n=e$ implies $b^n=e$'. But conjugacy is a symmetric property so its an if and only if statement. So to be clear you can just swap $a,b$ in the proof to see that $a^n=e$ if and only if $b^n=e$. Letting $n$ be the smallest possible $n$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach: for any $g \in G$ let the map $\phi_g : G \rightarrow G$ be defined by $\phi_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$. It is easy to check that this is an automorphism of $G$. Hence in your case, $b=\phi_g(a)$ has the same order as $a$.